# How to Add a a List of CString values into a ComboBox in MFC C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, combobox, mfc

I have a `CString` which is like this:

```
CString cstring = "Aaaa\nBadsalkjhf\nSM876\nSKSJDJHALSD";
```

How to add each of those CString and add these items as list in a ComboBox (MFC, C++).

Comment: *"each of those CString"* - it's unclear, what that is supposed to mean. There is only a single `CString` here.

Comment: First, learn how to split the string on delimiters of your choosing. Second, learn how to put *a* string in a combo-box using MFC, Finally take the strings from the First, and utilize the Second to add them. At least that's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
CStringA cstring = "Aaaa\nBadsalkjhf\nSM876\nSKSJDJHALSD";

// transfer to stringstream to ease splitting 
std::stringstream ss;
ss << cstring.GetString();
std::string str;

// splitting using "\n" as the delimiter
while (std::getline(ss,str,'\n')) {     
    ComboBox.AddString(str.c_str());
}
```

**Edited:** For Unicode

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include"atlstr.h"

void main()
{

    CStringW cstring = L"Aaaa\nBadsalkjhf\nSM876\nSKSJDJHALSD";

    // transfer to stringstream to ease splitting 
    std::wstringstream ss;
    ss << cstring.GetString();
    std::wstring str;

    // splitting using "\n" as the delimiter
    while (std::getline(ss, str, L'\n')) {
        ComboBox.AddString(str.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative would be to use [CString::Tokenize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#tokenize): `CStringW str; int index{ 0 }; str = cstring.Tokenize( L"\n", index ); while ( index != -1 ) { ComboBox.AddString( str.GetString() ); str = cstring.Tokenize( L"\n", index ); }`. Less code, and fewer dependencies.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks, didn't know that.